# Unable to consume the web API with header using API KEY dot net

Tags: .net, webapi

I am unable to consume the weather API. I am getting this message "Unathorized or not getting the response". I am not getting the http response. Please help me to get the response. When I try the URL and headers in post man i am getting the below output. Please help me on this. I think my correct is incorrect.

**Code in console application dot net Visual 2022:**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var responsetask = client.GetAsync("https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/ip.json?q=100.0.0.1");

responsetask.Wait();

if (responsetask.IsCompleted)
{
    var result = responsetask.Result;
    result.Headers.Add("X-RapidAPI-Host", "weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com");
    result.Headers.Add("X-RapidAPI-Key", "API KEY");
    
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var messagetask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(messagetask.Result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Excepted output:

```json
{
    "ip": "100.0.0.1",
    "type": "ipv4",
    "continent_code": "NA",
    "continent_name": "North America",
    "country_code": "US",
    "country_name": "United States",
    "is_eu": "false",
    "geoname_id": 4952762,
    "city": "Tewksbury",
    "region": "Massachusetts",
    "lat": 42.6028,
    "lon": -71.2319,
    "tz_id": "America/New_York",
    "localtime_epoch": 1653060449,
    "localtime": "2022-05-20 11:27"
}
```

Comment: You said "I am getting this message.", but you didn't specify what is the message.
My advice: Do not publicly post your X-RapidAPI-Key value for security reasons.

Comment: @NickPapadiochos Thank you I have updated the question. Please check now. I think my code is incorrect. Whether i am sending the header in right way.

Comment: You might have to delete this question completely, as anyone can click "edited xx ago" to access the old version and see your API key. Or see how you can deprecate that key. BTW, the answer below is correct, that you wrongly modify the response headers, instead of the request headers, to include your key and that's the wrong way.

Comment: you arnt setting authentication headers on the request. looks like you setting them on the response :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be adding your auth key to the header before executing the http request, and not after you get the result.